# Should Portfolio Site Backgrounds Be Static?

Tags: website-design, design, portfolio, professionalism

I am currently working on my portfolio site, and currently have a color wave effect in the background. It started as just a fun thing, but has become the background to the site, meaning I have no hesitation to remove it if need be.

My question is would something like this be professional, or seem kinda tacky or amateur?

If I kept it I would have to do some work to make sure the colors didn't conflict with the main content, but it shouldn't be to bad.

Thanks!

Comment: we can't really answer this without context. Even then, it's mostly subjective opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a UX professional - who is your target audience? List them. Think about the people you know who are in those roles (obviously asking / testing would be a the best of all solutions.)

To start the ball rolling you have headhunters and HR staff who look at your site; BAs, Project Managers, Creative Directors, UX/UI/IA Professionals and others.

What are their intentions in looking at your portfolio? 
What are your goals with the portfolio? (Do your goals mesh with their intentions?) If not is that to your benefit or not?

You first have to get past the headhunters and HR staff. Nobody else will look at your site if they reject you. Some of them will not care about color and some (Creative Directors) will be exacting in their examination of your use of color.

**All in all - know your target audience(s).**